# Удаление данных из Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Всем здравствуйте! Пишу приложение, работающее с FireBase. Через приложение заношу данные в базу, необходимо, чтобы они хранились в ней **ровно сутки**! Возможно ли как-то сделать ограничение по времени хранения?